# How to connect api in laravel of flutter apps?

Tags: flutter, laragon

How can I connect my flutter apps with laravel api? Below is what I post in postman.

> http://10.0.2.2/voyce/api/register

I try to run the API in postman and it does not give any response.

here is my api.dart in flutter.

---

**api.dart**

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
class CallApi{
    final String _url = 'http://10.0.2.2/voyce/api/';

    postData(data, apiUrl) async {
        var fullUrl = _url + apiUrl + await _getToken(); 
        return await http.post(
            fullUrl, 
            body: jsonEncode(data), 
            headers: _setHeaders()
        );
    }
    getData(apiUrl) async {
       var fullUrl = _url + apiUrl + await _getToken(); 
       return await http.get(
         fullUrl, 
         headers: _setHeaders()
       );
    }

    _setHeaders() => {
        'Content-type' : 'application/json',
        'Accept' : 'application/json',
    };

    _getToken() async {
        SharedPreferences localStorage = await
        SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        var token = localStorage.getString('token');
        return '?token=$token';
    }
}
```

All I want it to make the api able to connect? I think maybe there is something wrong with my laravel API but I dont have any idea where to fix it.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: in postman i got `Could not get any response`.

Comment: Issue is with flutter or laravel?

Comment: well I'm not sure since before this I use laravel for ionic

Comment: but in flutter I got some kind of error says `SocketException` error `connection refused`

Answer (score 0):

If you've encounter the error `SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused`, this is most likely a [network connection error](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23147). When trying to post the url in the browser and you get the proper response, then the problem could be in the postman. But you can refer [here](https://medium.com/swlh/authenticating-flutter-application-with-laravel-api-caea30abd57) for more details on how to integrate Laravel in Flutter.